# How to show a div with controls over full screen iframe

Tags: z-index, fullscreen

I want to show a close/cancel button on full screen youtube video, but youtube video iframe has z-index `2147483647` and I have also set same z-index to my div but it is not showing above iframe.

Here is my code :

```
<body>
...
// some other content
...
<div id="custom_button">close</div>
// iframe
</body>
```

I have used below code to full screen iframe :

```
var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
if (requestFullScreen)
{
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframe)();
}
```

And I have set css for custom_button :

```
z-index: 2147483647;
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
right: 1%;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
```

But it is not showing above full screen iframe.

How to do that?

Comment: z-index should be higher than the one you have for iframe. Not equal. Thus you avoid to check which element is rendered first.

Comment: I have also tried with higher z-index but not working.

Comment: Any progress on this?